# List constructor does not work properly in java

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to run the following code:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
ArrayList<Integer> val = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
```

i know that i get the list in the first line but I ran it out of curiosity. To my disbelief, val list is empty after running of the above code, at least on my Eclipse Indigo, java 1.6 machine. Any ideas?

Comment: I got `val` with 3 elements, exactly as expected. Same setup as yours. How did you test the `val` contents?

Comment: Well, I blame Linux for this and my uni machine. This piece of ***** suddenly prints it correctly but I swear to god it wasn't 5 mins ago...

Comment: I somehow doubt that it's Linux or your machine's fault.

Comment: I guess it was my fault after all... Sorry for wasting everybody's time. this can be closed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
        ArrayList<Integer> val = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
        System.out.println(val.size());
    }
}
```

works fine for me (it outputs `3`).  Your problem must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
List<Integer> val = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
System.out.println(val);
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as the other answers, but expressed as a unit test - your code works fine.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class ArrayTest extends TestCase {
    public void testArray() throws Exception {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        ArrayList<Integer> val = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
        assertEquals(3, list.size());
        assertEquals(3, val.size());
    }
}
```